# Symfony3 demo project don't work: PDO Exception Could not find driver (sqlite case)

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, symfony

Recently i've created Symfony3 project by command:

```
symfony new myproject
```

The project uses mysql and it works fine.

After that i've created demo project to study symfony best practices:

```
symfony demo
```

Project was created successfully. Config.php shows, that everything is ok. app_dev.php was successfully opened in my web browser. But when i try to open "http://localhost/app_dev.php/ru/blog/" (there is a public part of the app) 500 internal server error will appear. /app_dev.php/ru/blog/ shows:

**Error message:**

> An exception occured in driver: could not find driver
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - DriverException
>
> 2 linked Exceptions:
>
> PDOException »
>
> PDOException »

**Critical part in call stack:**

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occured in driver: could not find driver" at /var/www/symfony_demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractSQLiteDriver.php line 85

I've read all stack exchange issues about PDO Exception, but none helps me...

I use Ubuntu, Nginx.

Mysql, sqlite, php5-sqlite, sqlite3, libsqlite3-dev are installed. Nginx and php5-fpm are restarted. php.ini SQLite 3.x driver for PDO Wez Furlong.

Demo app parameters.yml:

```
database_driver: pdo_sqlite
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: null
database_user: root
database_password: null
database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/blog.sqlite'
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: secret_value_for_symfony_demo_application
```

php.ini file:

```
[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =
```

I have no idea, what is the reason of the problem and how to resolve it.

Help please!

Comment: run `php app/check.php`

Comment: php app/check.php shows 3 errors: app/cache, app/logs must be writable, timezone should be set. But it's all about cli. Web server permissions and timezone are correct. web/config.php shows "Your configuration looks good to run Symfony"

Comment: double check phpinfo() (if you are running symfony in dev environment - there is link to phpinfo in developer toolbar) - if you have both pdo and pdo_sqlite extensions enabled

Comment: also, check if in config.yml you have `driver` set as `"%database_driver%"` (so it takes the one from parameters.yml), because in new symfony installations there is pdo_mysql by default

Comment: doctrine dbal driver is %database_driver%. php.ini pdo drives: mysql only in enable column

Comment: yeah, pdo_sqlite is not enabled. You need to enable it, but it might not be in /etc/php.ini, it could be for example file /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, where you need to uncomment (remove ; from beginning of the line) line extension=pdo_sqlite.so

Comment: There are two files in config.d: 1) '@sqlite3.ini with extension=sqlite3.so, 2) '@pdo_sqlite.ini with extension=pdo_sqlite.so. Both were uncommented.

Answer (score 13):

Just install:

```
sudo apt install php-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 9):

For me in ubuntu that work

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-sqlite
```

Comment: Worked for me with PHP7 and `sudo apt install php7.0-sqlite3`. A more general/abstract solution would be something like that:  `sudo apt-get install phpX.Y-sqlite`

Answer (score 2):

On my system, this worked.  Might not be for everyone though:

1. I had used Symfony earlier this year, with PostGRESQL
2. Today I did what I **thought** was a clean symfony project install, using composer and the directions at symfony.com
3. I got the error you described \
4. I looked at everything. Finally saw, for some reason, my .env was set to use postGreSQL.  Commented that line back out of the /.env file and set it for SQLite:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```